# getAllowAttributes this Returning NULL - Magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm having a problem when I try to get the attributes of the product but only returns me NULL.

I'm trying the following:

```
<? php
require 'app/Mage.php';
$app = Mage::app('default');

  try {
     $id = '4';
     $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
     $_attributes = $product->getAllowAttributes();

     var_dump($_attributes);

   } Catch(Exception $e){
     echo $e->getMessage();
   }

?>
```

I do not know if my product is lacking in something, if you really have to have something in the configurable product, please let me know what you should have.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such method in the product model. So `getAllowAttributes` will always return null unless you have an attribute called `allow_attribtues` or you call this prior to calling your method: `$product->setAllowAttributes('something')`.
If you are looking for a way to get the attributes that are allowed for building a configurable product this is what you need:

```
$attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributes($product);
```